# Union All especificar select no order by

Tags: sql, order-by, union, union-all

Tenho UMA tabela teste e estou fazendo um Union All e quero ordenar pela data, mas sem ordenar pelo primeiro select antes do Union All que seria um cabeçalho título. Gostaria de ordenar apenas os dados do segundo select, poderiam me ajudar? O primeiro select deve ficar fixo na primeira linha pois é como se fosse uma descrição da coluna.

```
SELECT

'NOME_FUNCIONARIO',
'DATA_FUNCIONARIO' 

UNION ALL

SELECT NOME
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATA,106) 

        FROM B
        ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: Para que este cabeçalho !?

Comment: Se a cláusula ORDER BY deve ser aplicada a apenas um dos SELECT que participam da UNION então utilize parênteses, caso contrário se aplicará ao resultado da UNION. No seu caso coloque o segundo SELECT entre parênteses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almino, não sei se você vai obter as linhas na ordem esperada caso esteja (como parece que está) convertendo a data em um formato que não seja ano, mês e dia, mas de qualquer forma, segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
SELECT
  'NOME_FUNCIONARIO',
  'DATA_FUNCIONARIO',
  0
  
UNION ALL

SELECT
  NOME,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATA,106),
  1
FROM B

ORDER BY 3, 2
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Obrigado deu certo!

Answer (score 1):

Inclua uma coluna para realizar a ordem por select e ordene por isso por primeiro, o resto fica igual.

```
SELECT NOME, DATA
  FROM (SELECT 'NOME_FUNCIONARIO' nome, 'DATA_FUNCIONARIO' DATA, 1 ordem
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NOME ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATA,106), 2 ordem
          FROM B
         ORDER BY 3, 2)
```

Comment: Obrigado, testei dessa forma e funcionou também